# Import CSV NBA Stats in Excel

Tags: python, json, excel, csv, web-scraping

So after struggling a long time I've found a way to get the data from nba.com in comma separated values

This is the result http://stats.nba.com/stats/leaguedashplayerstats?DateFrom=&DateTo=&GameScope=&GameSegment=&LastNGames=15&LeagueID=00&Location=&MeasureType=Advanced&Month=0&OpponentTeamID=0&Outcome=&PaceAdjust=N&PerMode=Totals&Period=0&PlayerExperience=&PlayerPosition=&PlusMinus=N&Rank=N&Season=2015-16&SeasonSegment=&SeasonType=Regular+Season&StarterBench=&VsConference=&VsDivision=

How do I get that into a nice CSV or excel file?
Or even better if possible, how can I automatically query this data like web querying a table through excel web query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following should get you started:

```
import requests
import csv

url = "http://stats.nba.com/stats/leaguedashplayerstats?DateFrom=&DateTo=&GameScope=&GameSegment=&LastNGames=15&LeagueID=00&Location=&MeasureType=Advanced&Month=0&OpponentTeamID=0&Outcome=&PaceAdjust=N&PerMode=Totals&Period=0&PlayerExperience=&PlayerPosition=&PlusMinus=N&Rank=N&Season=2015-16&SeasonSegment=&SeasonType=Regular+Season&StarterBench=&VsConference=&VsDivision="

data = requests.get(url)
entries = data.json()

with open('output.csv', 'wb') as f_output:
    csv_output = csv.writer(f_output)
    csv_output.writerow(entries['resultSets'][0]['headers'])
    csv_output.writerows(entries['resultSets'][0]['rowSet'])
```

This would produce an `output.csv` file starting as follows:

```
PLAYER_ID,PLAYER_NAME,TEAM_ID,TEAM_ABBREVIATION,AGE,GP,W,L,W_PCT,MIN,OFF_RATING,DEF_RATING,NET_RATING,AST_PCT,AST_TO,AST_RATIO,OREB_PCT,DREB_PCT,REB_PCT,TM_TOV_PCT,EFG_PCT,TS_PCT,USG_PCT,PACE,PIE,FGM,FGA,FGM_PG,FGA_PG,FG_PCT,CFID,CFPARAMS
201166,Aaron Brooks,1610612741,CHI,31.0,13,6,7,0.462,17.5,105.8,106.8,-0.9,0.243,2.4,25.9,0.015,0.077,0.046,10.8,0.5,0.511,0.198,95.84,0.065,36,85,2.8,6.5,0.424,5,"201166,1610612741"
203932,Aaron Gordon,1610612753,ORL,20.0,15,3,12,0.2,23.0,98.9,106.4,-7.5,0.1,1.91,15.7,0.089,0.228,0.158,8.2,0.575,0.608,0.151,94.16,0.124,46,87,3.1,5.8,0.529,5,"203932,1610612753"
1626151,Aaron Harrison,1610612766,CHA,21.0,7,3,4,0.429,4.2,103.3,95.4,7.9,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.08,0.08,0.08,16.7,0.0,0.0,0.095,100.22,-0.032,0,5,0.0,0.7,0.0,5,"1626151,1610612766"
```

Comment: Thank you very much ! I tried using an online converter since I don't really have any programming skill but that messed up quite a bit of information.
Thank you so much for taking your time for this!

Comment: Great, I'm glad it worked, if you are happy with the answer, you can click on the grey tick to accept the solution.